# Error: Failing to install Tidyverse package

Tags: r, tidyverse

Below is the exact error code. I am new to R, RStudio, and tidyverse.  I did load Tidyverse two years ago for a class on the same computer but have not used it since.  Below is the exact error code.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘purrr’ 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
```

I have turned both the R program and R studio off and on again, and turned my computer off and  on again. The same error occurs.  I may uninstall and reinstall R to see if that helps.

Comment: Try install.packages("purrr")

Comment: Honestly, if you haven't done anything R-related in two years, I would do a fully fresh install. Install the latest version of R, Rstudio, and the packages you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will be doing that in addition to what I did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the purrr package was out of date, which it actually says in  the last line of code.  I just needed time to stop and think.